# Combining multiple tables into a custom view model

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, theory

First post here. I'm pretty new to programming and I am brand new to MVC and entity framework. I have a question that involves a lot of detail and a lot of code for attempts I've tried, but before I lay all that down, I thought I'd ask a question to see if I'm approaching the problem from the right paradigm.

I'm working on a project where my team is replacing an Access-based desktop app with an MVC web app. We have a single parent table with a one-to-many relationship with multiple other tables, and we've pulled that schema into our project as an mdf file and are, so far, trying to execute this thing database first.

Primary key of the master table is, say, CustomerID. All the child tables have CustomerID as a foreign key. What the app needs to do is display data from selected cells from all of the different tables for a single CustomerID.

The way I'm trying to attack this is I've created a model class that contains only the columns that I need to display, then in a controller I query the database with a series of left outer joins on CustomerID and select just the columns I want, and populate a single instance of the custom model that I made in the select clause. Then I pass that model to a View.

Basic question, I know, but is that the general process that is best? Or do I need to be thinking about this in a different way?

Comment: That sounds plausible for a display view. For a create or update view you will need different models that include the child collections. If you are using EF you shouldn't need the joins - you can eagerly grab what you need using include syntax: _context.Customers.Include(c => c.Invoices).Include(c => c.Addresses) etc. You can use a tool like Automapper to move your entity data into the models.

Comment: Thanks @Steve! I appreciate the quick comment. Include looks like it will be helpful, and thanks for the heads up about different models for create and view.

Comment: While it it not best practice in general, you can pass your entity class with all `Include`'s directly to your view. It will work well for CRUD applications.

Comment: Sounds like he is building view models from the entities. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but I ended up creating a model that consisted of lists of each of the tables I needed to draw data from.

So
    public class MasterModel
    {
        public List Names { get; set; }
        public List Emails {get; set; }
        public List Phones {get; set; }
    }

and then

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    MasterModel masterModel = new MasterModel();
    masterModel.Names = *query NamesTable where Names.id == id*
    masterModel.Emails = *query EmailsTable where Emails.id == id*
    masterModel.Phones = *query PhonesTable where Phones.id == id*

    return View(masterModel)
}
```

So that passes masterModel to index.cshtml, and index.cshtml pulls up a partial view for _NamesPartial.cshtml, _EmailsPartial.cshtml, and _Phones.cshtml. Each of those partials has a model of type IList, etc.

So then each of those partials has code like

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.TextBox("FirstProp", item.FirstProp)
    @Html.TextBox("SecondProp", item.SecondProp)
}
```

And that gets all my data displayed on one page.

So that problem is 'solved'.

But it does leave me with the new question of how to use this same method/model to write to each of the many databases using just one controller and model.